# Is it possible to change z-index for a child element of a div even with some workarounds or hacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, I need to visually placing the `parent` div on top (covering) the `child` div.

I read other questions, an I am aware that `child` is on a different flow, also I understand that the easily solution would be to place `parent` and `child` on the same level, nevertheless I am interested to know if there is any **workaround/hacks** that could make the trick.

I targeting only the latest version of Chrome and Firefox, any solution CSS3 also is welcome.

Notes:

- I need to keep the z:index on the parent.
- In my real code the parent is transparent, it need to grab user interecation.
- Child cannot be hidden, must be visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/qn3n4ynw/1/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>

#parent {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index: 100;
}
#child {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do yo need this?

Comment: Should / is the parent covering the entire child div?

Comment: What should be the result? If the child element has to be under the parent, it won't be visible.

Comment: If you could tell the reason you want to do this, it might be possible to find a workaround with the same result. Do you have access to how the HTML is built up? What is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a complex html structure provided by a legacy cms. I cannot change the source HTML. In my real world case the parent is covering the child but with opacity 0, it grabs user interaction like mouse drag, the child is only a visual placeholder and it should be visible.

Comment: you can set the child divs opacity to 0

Comment: @NifalMunzir thanks, but I need the child to be visible.

Comment: @GibboK.. can you please explain _In my real code the parent is transparent, it need to grab user interecation_. the doubt I have is when parent is transparent why so much struggle to put the child back? What's the purpose? This helps us to understand it in more clear way.

Comment: Are the `parent` and `child` divs the same size? Can't you just put the user interaction on the `child`?

Comment: No they are not on the same size, child is always smaller that the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Remove z-index from `#parent` and change `z-index` of child to `-1`

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qn3n4ynw/5/)**

```
#parent {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#child {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: So easy! Still curious to why OP would want this though.

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned, but I think the OP needs the `Z-index: 100;` on the parent.

Comment: @Rvervuurt.. Even am curious.. :) There must be some serious need!! :)

Comment: @user1129884.. I think OP just mentioned `z-index` to `100` may be just to check if higher `z-index` lets the `parent` to cover `child`.. Not sure though!!

Comment: thanks guys but I need the z-index: 100; on the parent.

Comment: @GibboK.. Is it ok if `position:absolute` from `#parent` is removed?? **[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qn3n4ynw/11/)**

Comment: Woops, removed my comment. Any chance you can add a container with the `z-index:100;`? 
http://jsfiddle.net/qn3n4ynw/19/

Comment: Thanks for your comments... I need to keep position:absolute

Comment: how about @user1129884's solution??

Comment: I am ware that I can solve this issue placing on the same flow parent and child (this means also adding in the DOM a container). My question is related to any workarounds or hacks without modifying the HTML structure. Thanks guys for your time on this.

Comment: @GibboK Unless you want to change the DOM via javascript, I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to put a child div behind a parent div. Probable solution would be (if the parent is grater than the child and covering it entirely which is the case due to the above CSS):

make the child invisible and visible again

```
jQuery("child_selector").toggle(duration, function () { ... on complete });
```

**Edit**:

working [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qn3n4ynw/15/)